# SQL: How to dynamically loop & add N number of column with NULL value into temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Due to a certain requirement, I need to create two temp tables in Stored Procedure, after processing some data into them, I need to combine the two temp tables to show as one result set and generate into excel. So I'm thinking to use `UNION` when I want to show the final result set.

The issue is, the first temp table (Table A) is fixed to 20 columns, and the second temp table has 50 columns (Table B). My plan is, before processing data for Table A, I want to add 30 nullable columns and insert data for first 20 columns, and the rest is all `NULL`

After I process the data for Table B, I use `UNION` to combine Table A & B so that they will show as one result set.

What I can think of right now is to hard code some columns that are destined to have null values when I declare the temp table:

```
Declare @tmpTableA table (
  ....
  ProcessDate datetime,
  Mode int,
  Col21 varchar(10)
  Col22 varchar(10)
  ....
  Col50 varchar(50)
)
```

When I insert data into Table A, I have to manually add null from Col21 onwards

```
Insert into(.... Col21, Col22, Col23....)
Values (.... NULL, NULL, NULL....)
```

After I complete processing data for Table A & B, I use `UNION` to merge Table A and B

```
Select *....Col49,Col50 From Table A
Union
Select *....CompleteDate,ContactPerson From Table B
```

Instead of hard-coding Col21 to Col50 into Table A, is there any elegant way to achieve that like using `while` loop to dynamically add N number of columns into Table A?

EDIT:
According to latest requirement, Table B has not only 50 columns but 100 columns! I really need a way to dynamically loop those columns rather than hard-coding for over 80 columns

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just do

```
select * into #tableA from #tableB where 1=2
```

with this both tables will have same columns

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add columns to table A, just add 30 NULLs to select from Table A.

```
Select *,NULL,...,NULL,NULL From Table A 
Union
Select * From Table B
```

You could add aliases to make the result a bit cleaner

```
Select *,...,NULL CompleteDate, NULL ContactPerson From Table A
Union
Select * From Table B
```

Comment: Good suggestion. I can avoid a little trouble adding columns into Table A. But can I do looping to add N number of NULL in the SELECT statement to make it much more perfect?

Comment: Something like select * into TempC from TempB;
insert into TempC (Col1, ... , Col20) select * from TempA; might work,if the first 20 columns have identical names.